# I need help unpacking evolution-3.8.0.tar.xz

Tags: 13.04, evolution, 7zip

When I right-click the file and click run, I am told:

**There is no application installed for “Tar archive (XZ-compressed)” files.
Do you want to search for an application to open this file?**

When I search for files on line, the following pops up in a window:

```
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Python.xdg.Exceptions.ParsingError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/defer/__init__.py", line 489, in _inline_callbacks
result = gen.send(result)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sessioninstaller/core.py", line 1030, in _install_mime_types
path))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdg/DesktopEntry.py", line 33, in __init__
self.parse(filename)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdg/DesktopEntry.py", line 42, in parse
IniFile.parse(self, file, ["Desktop Entry", "KDE Desktop Entry"])
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/xdg/IniFile.py", line 81, in parse
raise ParsingError("Invalid line: " + line, filename)
ParsingError: ParsingError in file '/usr/share/app-install/desktop/workrave:workrave.desktop', Invalid line: - RSI (Repetitive Strain Injury) oraz wspomaga rekonwalescencj\u0119
```

I don't understand this!

I have 7zip installed which is supposed to extract this type of compressed file, but it is not offered to me when I right click on the file.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the terminal, change directories to the directory of evolution-3.8.0.tar.xz and run:

```
sudo apt-get install unp  
unp evolution-3.8.0.tar.xz
```

unp can also be used for extracting files from a .tar.gz archive while preserving the directory hierarchical structure of the archive (without needing to add any switches to the `unp` command).

Comment: *"preserving the directory hierarchical structure of the archive"* is really not a unique 'feature' - I can't even think of an unpack utility not providing this.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the packages 
[`liblzma5`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/liblzma5) [image: Install liblzma5]
and
[`xz-utils`](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/xz-utils) [image: Install xz-utils].

These provide support for handling of XZ-compressed archives for general system utilities, e.g. `tar --xz` support.